# Auto-delete a parent entity in a redux reducer when one of it children is empty

Tags: redux

I have a `Redux` reducer which handles among other things products. Each product has an array field named `productImages`. An action type `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS` removes a specific image from that array.

How can I automatically delete a product once all its `productImages` are removed?

I've tried using `useEffect` to no avail.

My codesandbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-delete-vi9exs?file=/src/App.js).

```
case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IF_NO_IMAGE:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.filter(
      (product) => product?.productImages?.length > 0
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update the list when you delete an image from the product.

```
case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state?.products
      .map((item, index) => {
        if (index !== action.payload?.productIndex) return item;

        return {
          ...item,
          productImages: item?.productImages.filter(
            ({ imageFileName = null }) =>
              imageFileName !== action?.payload?.imageFileName
          )
        };
      })
      .filter((product) => product?.productImages?.length > 0)
  };

case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IF_NO_IMAGE:
  return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling the purge method only once when the app loads:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(deleteProductIfNoImage());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

A more efficient way would be to introduce sub-reducers, it would make your task easier:

```js
const product = (state, action) => {
    const { productImages = [] } = state;
    const { imageFileName } = action.payload || {};

    switch (action.type) {
        case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                productImages: productImages.filter(
                    (productImage) =>
                        productImage.imageFileName !== imageFileName
                ),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const products = (state, action) => {
    const { productIndex } = action.payload || {};

    switch (action.type) {
        case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: products
                    .map((item, index) =>
                        index === productIndex ? product(item) : item
                    )
                    .filter((item) => item.productImage?.length > 0),
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const appReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: products(state, action),
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

If you follow this sub-reducers advice which Dan Abramov suggested in his online [redux course](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree) + switch to dictionaries and product ids, the reducer code would be much cleaner and possibly more maintainable:

```js
const product = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_CODE:
            return {
                ...state,
                newProductCode: action.payload.productCode,
            };
        case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_NAME:
            return {
                ...state,
                productName: action.payload.productCode,
            };
        case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY:
            return {
                ...state,
                productName: action.payload.productCategory,
            };
    }
};

const products = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_CODE:
        case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_NAME:
        case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    products: {
                        ...state,
                        [action.id]: product(products[action.id], action)
                    }
                }
    }
};
```

Furthermore, I recommend checking out [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started) which is the new redux standard for building stores and perhaps utilizing [immerJs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) instead of sub-reducers in your redux reducer code.

Comment: Can you fork my codesandbox with these codes? thank you.